# Toggling independent divs not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a toggle jquery snippet which appears to me like it should work, but it isn't. It is only allowing the first div to toggle. If I delete the first div set, the second one begins to work, so I know it's not a typo or anything.

JsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kits87/69qnosyb/1/

HTML

```
<div>
        <div id="ByteHeaderContainer">
            <div class="ByteHeadTitle"><p>Header</p></div>
        </div>

        <div id="Byte">Copy</div>
</div>       

    <br><br><br>

<div>
        <div id="ByteHeaderContainer">
            <div class="ByteHeadTitle"><p>Header</p></div>
        </div>

        <div id="Byte">Copy</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.ByteHeadTitle').hide();

$('#ByteHeaderContainer').click(function() {        
    $(this).next('#Byte').fadeToggle('fast');
    $(this).children('.ByteHeadTitle').fadeToggle('fast');   
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: IDs **must** be unqiue.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Changed it to classes and now it works. I knew it was something silly. Thanks!

Comment: there is no need of using jquery to hide the class ByteHeadTitle. Use css and should work(.ByteHeadTitle{
    display:none;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

`<div id="ByteHeaderContainer">`

to

`<div class="ByteHeaderContainer">`

and

`$('#ByteHeaderContainer').click(function() {`

to

`$('.ByteHeaderContainer').click(function() {`

Remember the Id's must be unique in your DOM, that's why you are only getting it to work with the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/66p2dj1q/

Change `#ByteHeaderContainer` to `.ByteHeaderContainer` in your HTML (change to class), CSS and jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` of each element need to be **unique**.

You may use classes instead but, a work around for your situation would be to replace your code by this:

```
$('[id="ByteHeaderContainer"]').click(function () {
    $(this).next('#Byte').fadeToggle('fast');
    $(this).children('.ByteHeadTitle').fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

[Here is the updated **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/69qnosyb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be unique. Try changing `#ByteHeaderContainer` to `.byteHeaderContainer` in HTML and JS, and it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I was just pointing out at this exact case. Yes, IDs of any element in page must be unique. I edited my answer, no need for downvote, thanks.